# Create structures in loop without naming them

Tags: c, struct

Let's say I want to create structures in a loop. I don't want to change the values of the structure variables in each loop, I want to create new ones. However, from what I've learnt until know I have to name every new structure I make. Is there a way to do it without naming the structures?

And more specifically, can I have a pointer in each structure that will point to the next one?

What I wanna make is a BST and my struct is for every new node I add to the tree.That's how I've seen people do it, with struct. How can I add nodes if I don't name them? I definitely have some blanks there.

Comment: Create structure *definitions*? Or creating structure *instances*? Can you perhaps show some pseudo-code of what you want?

Comment: @JohnKatsantas for clarification please don't post comments but edit your question.

Comment: You are probably looking for these notions: dynamic allocation, heap, malloc. This site is not a tutorial-on-demand so try googlin them.

Comment: maybe show us what your struct looks like now and then maybe we could understand your question better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c structures initializing using for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615620/c-structures-initializing-using-for-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a struct variable many times in the loop by using malloc() to allocate memory for each iteration

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct structname
{
int a;
struct structname* b;  //points to next struct
};
int main()
{
struct structname* ptr[10]; //
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
     ptr[i] = (struct structname*)malloc(sizeof(struct structname));
     ptr[i]->a=1;
     ptr[i]->b=NULL; //point to next struct instead of NULL
    }
}
```

However if you know the number of struct s before hand you can create an array to hold the struct s

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct structname
{
int a;
};
int main()
{
 struct structname array[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
     array[i].a = 1; //input number here
    //no need of pointing to next struct as its already in an array
     }
}
```

Comment: I getn an error in the line: struct structname array[10]. Array type has incomplete element type.

Comment: The problem is in the line I mentioned above. I thought it's because we don't declare the array. What type is the array here?

Comment: If we were to declare an integer array we write " int arrayname[];". But when we want to declare a structure array we write " struct structname arrayname[]; ". The type of array here is "struct structname"

Comment: It doesn't work. It says array has incomplete element type.

Comment: This error occur because in c language you need to specify the array size. Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: All good,I had the structure after main that's why it didn't work. Just what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, answer is no, you can't declare a structure without a name. And regarding pointer to the next structure member, you should read more about lists and double linked lists in C here http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists

Answer (score 0):

Rules for an Identifier

1. An Indetifier can only have alphanumeric characters( a-z , A-Z , 0-9 ) and underscore( _ ).
2. The first character of an identifier can only contain alphabet( a-z , A-Z ) or underscore ( _ ).
3. Identifiers are also case sensitive in C. For example name and Name are two different identifier in C.
4. Keywords are not allowed to be used as Identifiers.
5. No special characters, such as semicolon, period, whitespaces, slash or comma are permitted to be used in or as Identifier.

So, to answer your question you cannot create new structs without identifying them, and even if you were able to, what would you reference it by? 
If there is nothing pointing to a it, it is simply garbage taking space on the memory

Comment: As I said I'm trying to make a BST. My first structure would have the name root, it would be the root of the tree and it would contain a pointer to the next structure and each new structure would contain a pointer for the next one.

Comment: A BST where every node has only 1 child?

Comment: No, I'll create a BST with left and right child eventually.What I'm having trouble with right now, is pointing to a new structure without naming it.

Comment: You cannot point to something if you cannot identify it. To me it seems like using an array or similar data structure containing structs would perhaps be a better solution.